# Mask some part of devices in schematic

Tags: schematics, altium

I have a question about working with Altium Designer Software. I put some devices in schematic, but I do not want all of them importing to PCB. I mean I want to mask some part of schematic in such way that software does not import those parts into PCB. Would you please tell me how to do it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you just want to temporarily exclude things, use a compiler mask directive by right click and add. I do this to remove test points to check for no single net errors. Then once I'm good I include them all by turning the compiler mask off again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right-click on the component and select properties. Set the characteristic you want in the drop-down box on the dialog:

[image]

Mechanical parts will not show up on the PCB but will be included in the BOM.

Answer (score 3):

Double click the part in the schematic (or select multiple parts and use the inspector). Change the "Type" of the part to Graphical (or to Mechanical if you want it on the BOM even though it doesn't have a footprint on the PCB).

For more info on the options available, see [here](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADRR/Sch_Dlg-SchComponentPropertiesForm((Properties+for+Schematic+Component))_AD).